# Career Change Advice

Tags: job-search, human-resources, careers, employment

29, Unemployed. I hold majors in Computer Science but coding/programming is not for me. It has been more than 14 months I am unemployed, tried BPO Jobs lasted for just 6 months max. I am done with working as an agent in BPO, can't work in BPO as an agent.Looking for something stable, any career advice would be appreciated, but no programming/coding please.

Comment: How many jobs have you had since you left university? And, which country are you looking for a job. Not my DV, I don't have enough rep...but I think your question is off-topic here.

Comment: What is a BPO ?

Comment: @Fattie, Business Process Outsourcing probably.

Comment: "Everything but programming" is quite a lot to choose from :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing from both the name and the reference to call center jobs as BPO that you're not asking from the U.S.A.  If you add the country we may be able to give more specific advice.

> Programming is not for me

That's good.  You figured out what you don't want to do, and stopped doing it!  Other good news - you have a college degree.

**Next question - WHY!**

Why didn't you like programming.  Did you not like being inside all day?  The kind of task you were assigned? The hours?  Was there anything you liked about it?  You'll need to answer this question before anyone, including yourself, can give you career advice.

Why didn't you like BPO work?  Admittedly this is probably less important as many people don't like call center work, but use this experience to say "I don't like work involving X, but I enjoyed Y"